# MMRTG- thermal and electrical output

Tags: nasa, perseverance, rtg

I haven’t been able to find a definitive number for the thermal output (in watts) of the MMRTG used aboard the Perseverance rover. The numbers I’ve seen range from 1950 watts to over 2000. I also haven’t found a reliable number for the electrical output either. Some sources say 110 watts, some 145 and others 120.

A lot of sources contradict each other and even some NASA documents can’t seem to agree on a number. The only reliable number I’ve seen is that it has a minimum life time of 14 years.

Some of the articles I looked at -

[This NASA document](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/files/4_Mars_2020_MMRTG.pdf)

[This article from the Office of nuclear energy](https://www.energy.gov/ne/articles/powering-curiosity-multi-mission-radioisotope-thermoelectric)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia has some facts about [Plutonium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium-238):

> each gram of <sup>238</sup>Pu spontaneously generates 0.568 W of heat.

There is 3,478 g of <sup>238</sup>Pu at the start of the mission. The product of both numbers is 1975.5 W. That fits well to the 1,975 W in the document.

[image]

Some sources you found simply rounded 1975.5 W to either 1950 or 2000 W.

There was an early design goal for the [MMRTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-mission_radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator) of 125 W electrical power. For the rovers [Curiosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiosity_(rover)#Rover_and_lander_specifications) and [Perseverance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perseverance_(rover)) both :

> approximately 110 watts at launch with little decrease over the
> mission time
> are specified.

The electric power of the thermocouples depends on cooling influenced by the environment. On a cold day on Mars it may be 120 W, on a warm day only 110 W. (At the beginning of mission).

The Perseverance rover will need about half a year to Mars. The half-life of <sup>238</sup>Pu is 87.75 years. After 0.5 years 99.606 % of <sup>238</sup>Pu will remain, the heat power will drop from 1975 to 1967 W. 13.7 g of the <sup>238</sup>Pu will be decayed during the flight.

But the decay of <sup>238</sup>Pu does not start at launch, <sup>238</sup>Pu starts to decay when it is synthesized. If it waits 5 years for launch, 3.87 % of it is decayed. Thermal power will be reduced from 1,975 W to 1,898 W during this time.

Comment: `+1` I've just asked [Why exactly does curiosity's RTG make more electricity on cold days?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45932/12102)