# Heating Perseverance components prior to deployment

Tags: mars, perseverance

How is the heat generated by the MMRTG distributed to the operational parts of Perseverance prior to deployment?

Comment: Different question but related: [Now that Perseverance is “hot” (RTG in place) and before it gets to deep space, how will it stay cool?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45525/12102)

Comment: "prior to deployment" is in your title, so I've copied it to the body of your question as well.

Comment: If I had seen your question of 7 months ago and the informative answers I would have, at least, rephrased my question

Comment: The ultimate goal is the generation of good answers to op-topic questions and to guide future readers to those answers and to learn interesting things in the process :-)

Comment: new here and still learning the etiquette and ways to search for previously asked questions

Comment: You're doing just fine, don't worry about it! :-)

Answer (score 3):

After lots of searching I can partially answer my own question: The MMRTG produces a constant 2 kW of heat about 5% of which is converted into electrical power to charge the batteries, some of the excess heat is used via heat exchangers to heat up a CFC fluid which is pumped throughout the rover's body, the gold pipes on the MMRTG fins are part of this heat exchange system.

- [MMRTG- thermal and electrical output](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45918/12102)

Comment: I think (but can not find a source yet) that there is even a loop of "hot water plumbing" that goes to the spacecraft itself, and those lines have to be disconnected before separation. So I've just asked [Are there fluid disconnects that sever just before Curiosity and Perseverance separate?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50595/12102)

Comment: if you go back to the photo taken by Perseverance of its own top deck shortly after landing you can see just to the right of the umbilical cutter a group of severed cables and 2 or 3 severed pipes/tubes, I suspect these tubes carried the heated fluid from the MMRTG up to skycrane to keep it operationally warm and were severed just before separation

Comment: Oh please consider adding that (along with the photo) as another answer to my question; that's exactly the "disconnect" I'm interested in!